# Disable mouse clicks during long-running process?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an issue where when a button is clicked and the process takes a while, the user clicks on other locations on the GUI screen.  Those button clicks get queued up in the dispatcher so after the initial button click those other locations get clicked.  I want to prevent this from happening so other UI controls don't get clicked after it's done processing.

The only solution I can think of is to p/invoke into the mouse events and prevent them from being passed to the application while the button click is being processed.  Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the process takes a while, it is generally recommended to perform such process in a worker thread, rather than in a GUI thread. So use `BackgroundWorker` approach like in this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58836/Using-Background-Process-in-WPF.aspx), and then use `CanExecute` method of commands associated with specified buttons, like here:

[WPF Commanding – When do Commands re-evaluate their CanExecute method?](http://robburke.net/2008/04/wpf-command-pattern-when-does-it-query-canexecute/)
[WPF – CanExecute refreshed](http://terreaux.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/wpf-canexecute-refreshed/)

**EDIT:**

You can bind `IsEnabled` property of your other controls to the result of Command's CanExecute method.

[How to disable combobox when command canExecute returns false](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/65940ccd-9c18-4783-b7ec-91958cd9acf7/)
[How to bind a ComboBoxItem's IsEnabled property to the result of a Command's CanExecute method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320553/how-to-bind-a-comboboxitems-isenabled-property-to-the-result-of-a-commands-cane)

Comment: These are great example of how to disable individual buttons after a click, however it does not prevent other buttons or UI components like combobox's from being clicked while that button command executed handler is being processed.

Answer (score 3):

One of the easier solutions to this is to have some sort of semi-transparent overlay (potentially with progress information) that you pop up when there are long-running tasks going on. That will reliably disable the entire UI until you remove the overlay (which keeps you from having to do a lot of changing/binding IsEnabled properties).

Comment: This does not work because the button clicks are still queued in the dispatcher while I click on that window.  So when the click is done and I dismiss the window, the queued up clicks begin to fire.

Comment: That sounds to me like you're not running your long-running task on a background thread. That should be the first thing you change. Once you do that, what I suggested will work to disable all controls while it is running (the mouse clicks won't queue up, they'll get processed by the overlay, which essentially just discards them). I didn't realize, initially, that you weren't running the process on a background thread.